# Generate a texte file of 3 columns from a function of 3 variables

Tags: export, list-manipulation

How to export a function f(x,y,z) as a table of 3 simple columns ?
When I use   `Export["result.txt", Flatten /@ data, "Table"]`, I don't get the data in the form:

x1,y1,z1

x2,y2,z2

x3,y3,z3

etc.

I would like to have only 3 columns (x,y,z) in my texte file...

Here a code as example

```
FF[a_, b_, c_] = a + b + c
data = Table[{a, b, FF[a, b, 1]}, {a, 0, 1, 0.1}, {b, 0, 1, 0.1}]
Export["result.txt", Flatten /@ data, "Table"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Join @@ data` instead of `Flatten /@ data`:

```
Export["result.txt", Join @@ data, "Table"]
```

to get three columns.

Compare

```
Dimensions[Join @@ data]
```

> {11, 33}

with

```
Dimensions[Flatten /@ data]
```

> {121, 3}